# Not able to search for string within a string in elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to setup the mapping for my elasticsearch instance with full name matching and partial name matching:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/?pretty=1'  -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "venue": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "name": {
          "fields": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "full_name"
            },
            "partial": {
              "search_analyzer": "full_name",
              "index_analyzer": "partial_name",
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "type": "multi_field"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "swedish_snow": {
          "type": "snowball",
          "language": "Swedish"
        },
        "name_synonyms": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms_path": "name_synonyms.txt"
        },
        "name_ngrams": {
          "side": "front",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 50,
          "type": "edgeNGram"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "full_name": {
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        },
        "partial_name": {
          "filter": [
            "swedish_snow",
            "lowercase",
            "name_synonyms",
            "name_ngrams",
            "standard"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I fill it with some data:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk?pretty=1'  -d '
{"index" : {"_index" : "test", "_type" : "venue"}}
{"location" : [59.3366, 18.0315], "name" : "johnssons"}
{"index" : {"_index" : "test", "_type" : "venue"}}
{"location" : [59.3366, 18.0315], "name" : "johnsson"}
{"index" : {"_index" : "test", "_type" : "venue"}}
{"location" : [59.3366, 18.0315], "name" : "jöhnsson"}
'
```

Perform some searches to test,
**Full name:**

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/venue/_search?pretty=1' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "text": {
            "name": {
              "boost": 1,
              "query": "johnsson"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "name.partial": "johnsson"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.29834434,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "venue",
        "_id": "CAO-dDr2TFOuCM4pFfNDSw",
        "_score": 0.29834434,
        "_source": {
          "location": [
            59.3366,
            18.0315
          ],
          "name": "johnsson"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "venue",
        "_id": "UQWGn8L9Squ5RYDMd4jqKA",
        "_score": 0.14663845,
        "_source": {
          "location": [
            59.3366,
            18.0315
          ],
          "name": "johnssons"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Partial name:**

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/venue/_search?pretty=1' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "text": {
            "name": {
              "boost": 1,
              "query": "johns"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "name.partial": "johns"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.14663845,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "venue",
        "_id": "UQWGn8L9Squ5RYDMd4jqKA",
        "_score": 0.14663845,
        "_source": {
          "location": [
            59.3366,
            18.0315
          ],
          "name": "johnssons"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "venue",
        "_id": "CAO-dDr2TFOuCM4pFfNDSw",
        "_score": 0.016878016,
        "_source": {
          "location": [
            59.3366,
            18.0315
          ],
          "name": "johnsson"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Name within name:**

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/venue/_search?pretty=1' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "text": {
            "ame": {
              "boost": 1,
              "query": "johnssons"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "name.partial": "johnssons"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.39103588,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "venue",
        "_id": "UQWGn8L9Squ5RYDMd4jqKA",
        "_score": 0.39103588,
        "_source": {
          "location": [
            59.3366,
            18.0315
          ],
          "name": "johnssons"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm only getting one venue back which is `johnssons`. Shouldn't I get both `johnssons` and `johnsson` back? What am I doing wrong in my settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `full_name` analyzed as a search analyzer for the `name.partial` field. As a result your query is getting translated into the query for the term `johnssons`, which doesn't match anything.

You can use [Analyze API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html) to see what how your records are indexed. For example, this command

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=partial_name&pretty=1' -d 'johnssons'
```

will show you that during indexing the string "johnssons" is getting translated into the following terms: "jo", "joh", "john", "johns", "johnss", "johnsso", "johnsson". While this command

```
 curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=full_name&pretty=1' -d 'johnssons'
```

will show you that during searching the string "johnssons" is getting translated into term "johnssons". As you can see there is no match between your search term and your data here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So i guess to get a more fuzzy result one would have to use partial_name as search_analyzer. But that would result in a less precise search result... How should I think in this case. Maybe specify a new front edgeNGram analyzer with higher min_gram and boost it..? How would you do this?

Comment: That's your typical precision vs. recall compromise. It’s very difficult to suggest something without knowing all your use cases and what types of "partial matches" you want to support. My personal preference is to use an analyzer that would convert different variations of the same or similar names to a single term (like snowball for phonetic filter) and if it's not possible handle spelling mistakes outside of search engine using a specialized spellchecker.

Comment: Aha ok. I might write another question about this =) Thank you for your time!